# how to get linkedin type icon in bottom navigation bar in android?

Tags: android, linkedin-api, android-tablayout, bottomnavigationview

In bottom navigation view of Linkedin android app
the home icon and also other changes a little bit when clicking on it, in the LinkedIn Android app. How to do that in Android?

Comment: there are several vector icons present in android studio add them to bottom navigation view

Comment: @SaurabhDhage no bro i am asking like when notification bell icon not clicked in app it is in vertical direction...and when we clicked it it tilted animated .how can we do that

Answer (score 0):

You can easily rotate view by passing its angle

```
 android:rotation="90"    // in XML layout

 view.rotation = 90f      // programatically
```

Comment: no bro i am not asking this icon also changes a little bit like in home icon if we click on it a chimney popped on icon and in notclicked state a normal home icon is there. please see linkedin app one time u will understand what i want to ask